# Prints duplicate lines based on first column

Tags: uniq, duplicate

I want to get lines where first column duplicates (I used number 32 becouse first column has always 32 characters). So far I've figured out:

```
sort | uniq -d -w 32 filename
```

The problem is that I want both lines, not only one. For example from:

```
283158c7da8c0ada74502794fa8745eb  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-amd64.iso
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-i386.iso
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-powerpc.iso
```

The output I want is:

```
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-i386.iso
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-powerpc.iso
```

Not

```
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-i386.iso
```

Which I get

Comment: Does `uniq -D` instead of `uniq -d` help?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
 ... | awk '{if ($1 in used ) {
               if (used[$1] != "" ) print used[$1] ;
               print ;} else used[$1]=$0 ;} '
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
[...] | perl -lane 'grep(@F[1], @x)?print:push(@x, @F[1])'
```

```
% cat in
283158c7da8c0ada74502794fa8745eb  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-amd64.iso
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-i386.iso
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-powerpc.iso
% cat in | perl -lane 'grep(@F[1], @x)?print:push(@x, @F[1])'
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-i386.iso
5717dd795bfd74edc2e9e81d37394349  ubuntu-6.10-alternate-powerpc.iso
```